# Calculating runtime of battery

Tags: electrical-engineering

I'm a CS guy so I am pretty clueless when it comes to electrical engineering, so maybe you people can help me with this one. I have a Battery with 550 mAh capacity. I also have a small e-paper display that has an operating voltage of 3.3 V. The screen only uses energy when it is refreshed. To refresh, it needs 0.0264 Watt. How can I calculate how often I can refresh the screen before the battery is empty? Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Depends on how accurate you want to get. Simplest approximation assumes that 550mAh holds over the voltage needed. You need to know how long a refresh takes, and battery voltage.  Supposing battery voltage is always 3.3 (it's not), that .0264 watts is 8 mA.  Supposing a refresh takes .5 seconds ( at that power), you get 900 refreshes per mAh... seems weird.  I suspect 26mW during refresh is flawed or time to refresh is longer; media needs power to retrieve data after all.